# Remove quoted strings in insert query

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I need to insert a whole string that has 4 single quotes in it, here is my example.

```
declare @string varchar(255)
set @string = 'https://outlook.live.com' blocked 'online mail client'
insert into [events] (event) values (@string)
```

I can change

```
set @string = 'https://outlook.live.com' blocked 'online mail client'
```

to

```
set @string = 'https://outlook.live.com' + 'blocked' + 'online mail client'
```

and that resolves the problem, but I'm taking the string from CSV with multiple different strings so how can I transform that string to bypass ' or remove them, or escape them.

Comment: How are you actually doing your import? Have you written code? Are you using a tool?

Comment: Insert using a parameterized query. That way, you don't need to escape quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Working with powershell I just did

```
$string = $i.event.Replace("'","")
```

that complete the whole string as one in the insert query.

Comment: If you post your powershell code someone may be able to help further. For example the *correct* way to solve this issue is by using [SqlParameters](https://davegugg.wordpress.com/2017/09/30/inserting-into-sql-server-from-powershell-using-parameters/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to double up on the quotes to put them in a constant string:

```
set @string = 'https://outlook.live.com'' blocked ''online mail client';
```

This string has two single quotes.  I don't know where the other two are.